# what is version in rake db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am `fairly new to ruby and ROR`. I have a couple of questions on migration. I had a look on the guides, but its confusing for me.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

```
class CreateUserModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self_up 
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :username, :string
      t.column :email, :string
      t.column :password_hash, :string
      t.column :password_salt, :string
    end

  def self_down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

1. When i searched google, i found on this command to run migration `rake db:migrate
   VERSION=20098252345`. I am confused on what is this VERSION doing
   with the command. I just have created a migration 0001_create_user_model.rb
2. The above is my `migration` table. What does it create when i
   run/execute this file. Does it create tables and models for me?

Comment: @vee: Rails 4 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Please see: [`Running Migrations`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations).

Comment: @Vee: do you see any problems with the file name and class name [ 0001_create_user_model.rb ]

Comment: Yes, I was not sure why you had the file name prefixed with `0001`.  For a moment, I thought you were on Rails 2, which is why I asked the question.  Can you share how you created this migration?

Comment: @vee: I followed the initial steps of this tutorial. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails

Comment: just run `rake db:migrate` and don't worry about the version option - that will create your database table; it will not create your models

Comment: I usually like to use rails generators to create my migration and model files, i.e. `rails generate model User username:string email:string password_hash:string password_salt:string` take a look at the migration file, it is prefixed with a number, that is used by rails to track which migrations have already be run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `20098252345` in `rake db:migrate VERSION=20098252345` is just a prefixed number given to the migration file which is located in `db/migrate` directory.It is just a `UTC timestamp(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)` to differ one file from another.The migration file which is generated will look like this `20098252345_create_user_model.rb`

From the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/migrations.html)

Internally Rails only uses the migration’s number (the timestamp) to identify them. Prior to Rails 2.1 the migration number started at 1 and was incremented each time a migration was generated. With multiple developers it was easy for these to clash requiring you to rollback migrations and renumber them. With Rails 2.1+ this is largely avoided by using the creation time of the migration to identify them. You can revert to the old numbering scheme by adding the following line to config/application.rb.

```
config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = false
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The version of the rake command is actually a time stamp for the year, month, etc...
This is to specify how far into your migrations you want to go.

You have many migration files in any typical app. Since all those migrations make changes to your database schema (i.e. which tables, table names, attribute columns of a table, etc)

Rails handles defining the schema (i.e. creating tables and specifying which attributes and columns tables have) by building them step by step from migrations.

this makes it convenient to edit the schema by rolling back and migrating forward... much like how any version control system does.

Now, you can specify a version to specify up to which migration you want to actually "migrate" to and define the schema to... OR you can just run `rake db:migrate` to run all your migration files to the very last one. I usually don't specify the version specifically, since I'm usually running all the migrations up to the latest one. It's just an option. If you need to roll back some migrations and change some stuff, there are commands like `rake db:rollback` with various options specifying the number of steps, etc., which you can google as well.

This usually works. If you have validations in your model for data records (i.e. rows) in your database tables, you may run into migration issues, which you can read more about in section 6 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html